# How To filter 3 related datagridviews

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have 4 DataGridViews which display the Main departments and 3 sub departments: Main Department, Sub Department1, SubDepartment2 and SubDepartment3.
I want to click on Main Department and want all the other DataGrids to re-filter based on the columns in the DataGrid directly above them.
E.g.
SubDepartment1 will show records related to MainDepartment
SubDepartment2 will show records related to SubDepartment1
SubDepartment3 will show records related to SubDepartment2

I have it working a little. I have methods written to fill each DataGrid and then call all these methods when I click on a record in the MainDepartment DataGrid.

this loads the main department

```vb
Private Sub loadmaindept()

    'Dim connstr As String = "database=fabjobs;data source=localhost;userid=root;password=1234"
    Dim connstr As String = ("server='" & My.Settings.setserver & "';
                                   userid='" & My.Settings.setusername & "';
                                   password='" & My.Settings.setpassword & "';
                                   database='" & My.Settings.setdatabase & "'")
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstr)
    Dim query As String = "select * from maindepartment"

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        dgmaindept.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dgmaindept.Refresh()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

this loads the Sub department 1 which is related to main department

```vb
Private Sub loadsub1dept()

    'Dim connstr As String = "database=fabjobs;data source=localhost;userid=root;password=1234"
    Dim connstr As String = ("server='" & My.Settings.setserver & "';
                                   userid='" & My.Settings.setusername & "';
                                   password='" & My.Settings.setpassword & "';
                                   database='" & My.Settings.setdatabase & "'")
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstr)
    Dim query As String = "select * from sub1department where MainDptid = '" & dgmaindept.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        dgsub1dept.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dgsub1dept.Refresh()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

this loads the Sub department2 which is related to sub department 1

```vb
Private Sub loadsub2dept()

    'Dim connstr As String = "database=fabjobs;data source=localhost;userid=root;password=1234"
    Dim connstr As String = ("server='" & My.Settings.setserver & "';
                                   userid='" & My.Settings.setusername & "';
                                   password='" & My.Settings.setpassword & "';
                                   database='" & My.Settings.setdatabase & "'")
    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstr)
    Dim query As String = "select * from sub2department where Sub1Dptid = '" & dgsub1dept.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        dgsub2dept.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dgsub2dept.Refresh()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

this loads the Sub department 3 which is related to Sub Department2

```vb
Private Sub loadsub3dept()

    'Dim connstr As String = "database=fabjobs;data source=localhost;userid=root;password=1234"
    Dim connstr As String = ("server='" & My.Settings.setserver & "';
                                   userid='" & My.Settings.setusername & "';
                                   password='" & My.Settings.setpassword & "';
                                   database='" & My.Settings.setdatabase & "'")

    Dim conn As New MySqlConnection(connstr)
        Dim query As String = "select * from sub3department where Sub2Dptid = '" & dgsub2dept.CurrentRow.Cells(0).Value.ToString & "'"

    Try
        conn.Open()
        Dim da As New MySqlDataAdapter(query, conn)
        Dim ds As New DataSet
        da.Fill(ds)
        dgsub3dept.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
        dgsub3dept.Refresh()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        conn.Close()
        conn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

this code calls all the other methods for the sub departments

```vb
Private Sub dgmaindept_CellClick(sender As Object, e As DataGridViewCellEventArgs) Handles dgmaindept.CellClick

    Try
        Dim index As Integer
        index = e.RowIndex
        Dim selectedrow As DataGridViewRow
        selectedrow = dgmaindept.Rows(index)

        lblmainid.Text = selectedrow.Cells(0).Value.ToString()
        txtmaindeptno.Text = selectedrow.Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        txtmaindescription.Text = selectedrow.Cells(2).Value.ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    End Try

    loadsub1dept()
    loadsub2dept()
    loadsub3dept()

End Sub
```

I want the grids to all filter automatically when I click on any record in the main department. It works as long as I have records in the sub department 1 but when I click on a main department record that does not have a sub department 1 record then I get Null reference unhandled error in the sub department 2 method.

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you'd define relationships between 4 tables in the dataset, then bind them through bindingsources; the filtering is taken care of automatically when you do this

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. just to clarify.  you saying that i shoild use the "inner join" statement in my query for each method to load the datagrids. e.g. "select * from sub2department INNER JOIN sub2department ON sub1department.Sub1Dptid=sub2department.Sub1dptid"

Answer (score 0):

Put your `loadXdept()` subs in a try/catch handler too